# Min and Max Value c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, max, min

So I have some code that i am writing for an assignment and I am stuck on finding the min and max values from 3 floats.  I am currently getting the error

/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/predefined_ops.h:121:39: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'float')
         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }

This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Name: Tanner Langan
//Student Number: 300224340
//Date: 2//16/2017
//Assignment 3


int main()
{
char c1;
float x1,x2,x3;

cout << "Please Enter 1 character and 3 float numbers. One at a time" << endl;
cout << "You must choose either X, N, V, or S for the character." << endl;
cout << "If you choose X the result displayed will be the the maximum of x1, x2, and x3" << endl;
cout << "If you choose N the result displayed will be the the minimum of x1, x2, and x3" << endl;
cout << "If you choose V the result displayed will be the the average of x1, x2, and x3" << endl;
cout << "If you choose S the program will terminate.";
cin >> c1;
cin >> x1;
cin >> x2;
cin >> x3;

while (c1 != 'S')
{
if(c1 == 'X' || c1 == 'x')
{
cout << "The max is" << std::max_element(x1,x2,x3) << endl;
main();
}
if(c1 == 'N' || c1 == 'n')
{

cout << "The min is" << std::min_element(x1,x2,x3) << endl;
main();
}
if(c1 == 'V' || c1 == 'v')
{
cout << "The average is" << (x1+x2+x3)/3 << endl;
main();
}

}
return 0;

 }
```

Comment: you need to use `std::min` and `std::max`

Answer (score 0):

[`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) don't work as you think. They actually take iterators to the sequence and a comparator, not just numbers. They also return iterators, not values, so read the docs and understand how to use them before trying to randomly call functions. There are examples on the pages I linked that should help you.